# Creating Issues on Board in Azure DevOps from API

Tags: azure-devops, postman, azure-devops-rest-api

My goal is to create issues on an Azure DevOps board using an API call as shown in this picture[image]

.  So each API call would do the same thing as pressing the New Item button in that picture.

This is the most relevant search result so far which doesn't have an examples to reference

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/boards/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

I haven't yet found any examples to reference in a Google web search, a video search, or in the existing code base.

I first want to create board issues through Postman, then build the code.

Do you have any examples of creating Azure DevOps board issues in Postman which I can reference?

Comment: You're looking at the wrong API. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, Daniel.  I gave an update in a comment to the answer based on that documentation link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the official doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP

API using to create work item:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${type}?api-version=6.0
```

Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

[image]

Body:

[image]

I am Using Basic Auth with DevOps PAT

[image]

In Azure DevOps UI

[image]

Comment: Thank you Kim, this is helpful.  

I made those changes and I'm now getting a 400 bad request error, "Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames" even after I turned off SSL Certificate verification in Postman's settings.  This is still progress since I no longer get "unauthorized" errors

Comment: My mistake, I got a 200 with only the Content-Type header present.  Thank you so much!