# Creating an item inside a single board of Azure DevOps from API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

For context, I just read this question [Creating Issues on Board in Azure DevOps from API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73952517/creating-issues-on-board-in-azure-devops-from-api/75488241)
I have the exact same goal, except the solution didn't address it enough in my opinion because it didn't create the element inside the board.

I am using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&tabs=HTTP, It works great, however, I cannot send my item in a specific team board, it always end in "Work Items" menu, did I miss a field or something ?

Comment: What do you mean by "inside a board"? This is controlled by the area path and the parent/child links between work items.

Comment: I want to have the same effect as clicking the "New Item" button when I'm in a board. Not just the "Work Items" menu under the parent "Boards" menu.
I'll take a look at the area path and links, thanks

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your board.... as an example, for Agile you have to create User Story, Feature, or Epic.

Additionally, check your team settings ([Define area paths and assign to a team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-area-paths?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser))... if it uses custom settings for Area Path, you have to add Area Path to your request body.